# Apps script post request return 405 code error, when postman works fine

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get list of some data from api.
Running locally works fine, but running from script return 405 code.

```
const header = {
  'X-TOKEN': 'TOKEN'
};
const urlRegions = 'URL';
function getList()
{
  const query = {
    "active": true,
    "size":100
  };
  const options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : header,
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(query),
    'contentType': 'application/json',
  };
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(urlRegions,options));  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlRegions, options);
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());

}
```

Error message

```
Exception: Request failed for http://bpm71.bas.kz returned code 405. Truncated server response:
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail of `Running locally works fine`? And, can you provide the official document of the API yo uwant to use?

Comment: in Postman, and in .net, also in node.js its works fine.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `in Postman, and in .net, also in node.js its works fine.`, can you provide your script? And, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: Here is [link](https://elma365.com/en/help/360004962211.html#/app/{namespace}/{code}/list_post) to document. [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_oHLEX2ycmxC6w9NirkwLJaxPf0HJIcQ?usp=sharing) to file

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: I confirmed your current issue. In the URL, when the POST request is run to `http://bpm71.bas.kz`, the error of `405 Not Allowed` occurs. So I thought that in the current stage, unfortunately, Google Apps Script might not be able to request the URL. From this situation, I understood my answer was not useful. So I would like to delete my answer. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: For example, as a workaround, when you open the Spreadsheet and run the script, how about requesting it using Javascript which is not Google Apps Script on a custom dialog of Spreadsheet? If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize. By the way, the official document you provided uses the URL like `{company}.elma365.{zone}`. But your script uses `bpm71.bas.kz`. How about this difference?